# How to deploy artifact with maven when i only got the final .jar?

Tags: java, maven, deployment, nexus

i have a jenkins build-pipeline in which the first job calls mvn clean package to compile and build my java project. The artifact is copied afterwards to a bunch of test-jobs which ensure the quality of my build. The last job in the chain should deploy the artifact to my nexus repository.

My question is now, how to i deploy the file to nexus when i only have the final jar myproject-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar with maven?

I tried

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file
```

but this plugin needs to get information about groupId, artifact id, version etc. Which i do not want to know in my deploy-job.
Isn't the information stored in the jar itself in some maven files?
I just want to say nexus, here is an artifact, take it.

Comment: Check this link: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html

Comment: Jenkins has built-in functionality to deploy to repositories - use that, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I would suggest thinking about changing this to a single job and have Maven build and package the artifact, have Maven test the artifact (use the integration test phase if this is going to take a while) and then have Jenkins deploy the artifact if all is well. You could use Maven to deploy but generally its better to have Jenkins do it after it is certain everything has successfully completed in the job.

Answer (score 2):

A jar built with Maven contains this information in the `META-INF/maven/` directory. There complete `pom.xml` file is found under `META-INF/maven/[groupId]/[artifactId]/pom.xml`.

So what you can do is write a small program that extracts this information and calls `mvn deploy:deploy-file` with the right arguments.

Unfortunately, you have to know the `groupId` and `artifactId` to get the file, so you can't easily open and parse it. But of course you can get the name of the (only) directory in `META-INF/maven` and the name of this directory's (only) subdirectory. It's kind of cumbersome, but it should work.

Note: 
There is also a `pom.properties` file containing the most important information, which is probably easier to parse than the `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems all backwards to me. I would change the flow around to

1. run  `mvn clean deploy` to get the library deployed to the repository manager (Nexus or so) or the local repository (less ideal in case you have multiple build nodes)
2. let the test jobs pick up the artifact from the repository as dependency (or scriped wget or whatever)
3. you are already done..

Answer (score -1):

Use the pom.xml file you used to generate the jar file. Retain that file as part of artifact and when you need to deploy manually, you can use it